# Передача в system("echo") имени файла введенного с клавиатуры

Tags: c++

При изучении C++ возникла такая проблема. Понадобилось создавать  файл с именем, введенным  с клавиатуры, если конструкция **'if(!in.is_open("file.txt")'**  возвращает **TRUE**. Для создания нового файла используется системный вызов *ECHO*, которому надо передать дополнительно переменную *FileName*.

Вся конструкция выглядит так:

```
{
    cout << "Enter file name(MAX 40 symbols): ";
    cin >> FileName[40];
    cout << "n\";
    system("echo",FileName[40]);
}
```

Где ругается на то, что слишком много параметров для вызова функции ***system()***. Подскажите, или как правильно передать параметр функции, или как просто сделать правильно?

Comment: А что означает конструкция `cin >> FileName[40];`?

Comment: *"Для создания нового файла используется системный вызов ECHO*" -- а что может быть использовано для удаления - моя фантазия отказывется ТАК буйствовать :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простите, но идея достаточно глупая... Чтобы просто создать файл - сделайте примерно так:

```
if (...) {
    ofstream of(FileName);
}
```

Все, этого хватит. Если же хотите позарез использовать `echo` - но так:

```
char buf[128];
snprintf(buf,128,"echo >> %s",FileName);
system(buf);
```

Comment: Спасибо. _Echo_ не принципиально, к сожалению, пока не очень хорошо понимаю работу некоторых вещей в c++,отсюда и глупости

Comment: Да не обижайтесь, все через это проходили. Просто вы же должны знать о том, как создать файл для записи... Да, если решение устраивает - закрывайте вопрос, приняв ответ ("птичка" слева от вопроса).

Comment: Даже не думал,мне не 20 лет,чтобы злиться или обижаться на других если сам чего-то не понимаю.  Спасибо за подсказки